# QGIS and QFIeld value relation widget filtering

Tags: qgis

I have two PostgreSQL tables:

1 table name "features"
1 table name material containing material types

In table "features" I have a "material" field set to value relation widget linked to the the material table.

I set the "multiple choice" button on.

Everything works for recording and I get these kind of values as "material":

```
feature 1 : {wood;metal}
feature 2: {metal;stone;brick}
```

and so on.

The problem is that when I want to filter my "features" table using the QGIS forms, I can't choose to filter my table using one value like metal or wood. The "contains" option is not available for value relation widget set field or lists (array) fields.

Am I doing something wrong here? Should I set the "material" field as an array field?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am late but I have come across with the same issue and I used the following: `"field_name" = '%value%'`. It is not recommended as it could match with more than one element expected when values are similar but it works if the values inserted are too different (like in your case: metal, stone, brick).